# Objective-C : reading from JSON file too slow for remote notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I'm trying to setup the new ios 10 push notifications that are mutable, and in the didReceiveRequest method I am trying to read some argruments, one that is stored in NSUserDefaults and one that is in a local JSON file like this:

```
- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger index = [defaults integerForKey:@"index"];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Words" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSString *word = dict[@"Irish"][index];

    self.bestAttemptContent.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", word];
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}
```

The problem is the method runs too slowly and doesn't finish. I know this is the case because apple warns about it and because if I replace that whole method above with a simple line that changes the title to a random string then it runs fine. Does anyone know how to make this faster or a way around this ?

What I'm trying to accomplish is each day the 'index' variable will increase when a daily push notification is recieved and it should read that index from the json file. So I basically want the user to receive the next string in the JSON file each day

Thanks

Comment: How big is your Words.json file?  Can you use a more efficient store, such as sqlite?

Comment: I thought about that. I found a way to get the words stored in User Defaults, but now am having some strange issue where when I ste the body text it returns Null.... On some text I know exists

Comment: Did you receive `serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire` ? Apple gives you 30 secs to handle that request, and it not looks like your code runs longer. The problem may be in some other place.

Comment: I agree that I think the problem may not be here. I found a way to store the word I want in NSUserDefaults and am still running into issues (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751398/onesignal-ios-10-push-notifications-cant-debug)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do the actual processing in a new thread and return to complete the method call:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
   self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
   ...
});
```

Comment: I will try this out, thanks. Will post back if it works.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Thank you for the advice anyway!